# Ampscript condition IF with OR

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I inserted the following Ampscript

```
%%[IF (@Color != "Red" OR @Color != "White") THEN]%% 

HTML 

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

The aim is to show a button (HTML) when the field Color is different from Red or White.
The output shows the button in the case the field Color is Red and in the case the field is Purple.

Comment: Shouldn't you replace the OR with an AND? because with an OR, Color != "Red" includes Color = "White", and the same for Color != "White"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you should change the condition *OR* to *AND*

So in case @Color is not red **AND** is not white, the button will be rendered.